# less under tmux treats wrapped lines as single lines, breaking paging

Tags: less

In `tmux` (v1.8), using `less` (v458) with a pipe or file that includes lines longer than the terminal width has started causing problems for me on Ubuntu.

The pager initially scrolls beyond the first line instead of starting at the top. When I try to scroll back, the characters from different lines run together into one block without newlines.

Sometimes, commands like page up (`b` or `<C-b>`) appear to jump *past* the end of the file, leaving a bunch of lines at the bottom:

```
some-line
another-line
last-line-in-file
~
~
~
~
~
(END)
```

From there, the pager can never be scrolled back up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out before I finished posting: I had aliased `less` to `less -r` to retain color, but apparently that screws up less:

```
-r or --raw-control-chars
       Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.  The  default  is  to
       display  control  characters  using the caret notation; for example, a
       control-A (octal 001) is displayed as  "^A".   Warning:  when  the  -r
       option is used, less cannot keep track of the actual appearance of the
       screen (since this depends on how the screen responds to each type  of
       control  character).   Thus, various display problems may result, such
```

I will either remove that alias or try using `-R` instead, which only retains ANSI color escape sequences and should work "in most cases".

After some time, `less -R` has been work exactly as I want and hasn't caused any display issues.

```
-R or --RAW-CONTROL-CHARS
       Like -r, but only ANSI "color" escape sequences are  output  in  "raw"
       form.   Unlike  -r,  the  screen appearance is maintained correctly in
       most cases.  ANSI "color" escape sequences are sequences of the form:

            ESC [ ... m

       where the "..." is zero or more color specification characters For the
       purpose  of  keeping  track  of  screen  appearance, ANSI color escape
       sequences are assumed to not move the cursor.  You can make less think
       that  characters other than "m" can end ANSI color escape sequences by
       setting the environment variable LESSANSIENDCHARS to the list of char‐
       acters  which  can end a color escape sequence.  And you can make less
       think that characters other than the standard ones may appear  between
       the ESC and the m by setting the environment variable LESSANSIMIDCHARS
       to the list of characters which can appear.
```